# Charging customer on behalf of shopkeeper using Stripe Connect?

Tags: c#, asp.net, stripe-payments, stripe.net

I am developing this using ASP.NET  and i have used Stripe.NET dll, according to the documentation I had linked up my shopkeeper stripe account with me and got the access code.

Now i have confusion about my customer, he should be added as customer in shopkeeper's stripe account or just his account is linked up with my Stripe account as Shopkeepers.

Can anyone please explain, how it will work ?

```
var stripeService = new StripeChargeService(sellerStore.StripeMerchantAccessToken); //The token returned from the above method
var stripeChargeOption = new StripeChargeCreateOptions() { 
AmountInCents = amountInCents,
Currency = "usd", 
CustomerId = buyerPaymentInfo.StripeCustomerToken,
Description = "Locabal",
ApplicationFeeInCents = locabalsCut 
};
var response = stripeService.Create(stripeChargeOption);
```

buyerPaymentInfo.StripeCustomerToken will be Access code or it will be the customer registered in Suppliers account ?

I want to charge customer using his Credit Card

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding of Stripe API, you should create a customer in your account and use customer ID which starts with "cus_" in the charge.

If you look at following stripe.net discussion you will see how to create a customer and use it in your charge.

https://github.com/jaymedavis/stripe.net/pull/43#issuecomment-30345043

```
//This is what we do to create a long-term customer in our system
//user is a user object unique to our system. We save it in our database
//stripeToken is what is generated by the Javascript on the page
var stripeService = new stripeCustomerService(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StripeSecret"]);
var stripeTokenOptions = new StripeCustomerCreateOptions { TokenId = stripeToken };
var response = stripeService.Create(stripeTokenOptions);

if (user.PaymentInfo == null)
{
    PaymentInfo paymentInfo = new PaymentInfo
    {
        StripeCustomerToken = response.Id
    };
    user.PaymentInfo = paymentInfo;
}
else
{
    user.PaymentInfo.StripeCustomerToken = response.Id;
}
```